# Adding fields to a Django form dynamically with JavaScript & JSONField

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I have a model form in which I need to store an unknown number of helpers alongside a thing. The names can be serialised upon save, and that's not a problem. It's being able to clean and validate them upon submission.

The form looks like;

```
class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for the Thing
    """
    owner = forms.CharField()
    helpers = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Thing

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Serialize helpers to JSON.
        """
        ...
```

And the model is using a JSONField to store the serialised helpers.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField()
    helpers = JSONField()
```

I have JavaScript adding as many helpers as required with the same input name:

```
<input name="helpers" value="Fred" />
<input name="helpers" value="Joe" />
```

Which is returning a tuple of the helpers. **The problem is that the if the form isn't valid - those names will be lost** and the cleaning isn't working.

My first thought was to add to the form's constructor:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            helpers = args[0].pop('helpers')
            for name in helpers:
                # Add a charfield, or something?
        except:
            pass
```

But I'm not really getting anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [AdamKG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16361/adamkg) for the answer to this. You can just use the list in your view again:

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    helpers = request.POST.getlist('helpers')
    form = ThingForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/saved/')
else:
    helpers = None
    form = ThingForm()

return render_to_response('my_template.html',
    {'helpers': helpers, 'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name == 'helpers' %}
        {% for name in helpers %}
            <input name="helpers" value="{{ name }}" />
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is do something like this in your template:

```
{% if form.data %}{# eg, was invalid and this is a re-render w/ errors #}
{% for helper in form.data.helpers %}
<input type="hidden" name="helpers" value="{{ helper }}">
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Note that this will break if you start passing a `prefix` kwarg to your form - but so would your original code, fixing that is a separate issue :)

Comment: The problem is that the extra helpers are cleaned by the form, so they don't exist by the time we get to the template.

Comment: Is this a clean method you added? It should still be in `form.data`, as long as you're passing the form bound with `request.POST` back to the template to render the errors.

Comment: No, the form is pretty vanilla now. If I use that iterator in the template and it just iterates the letters in the last input (there's only a string in form.data.helpers)

Comment: Ah, right. Just accessing the helpers key won't give you the list. You'll need to pass `{'prev_helpers': request.POST.getlist("helpers")}` as context to the template and iterate over that instead.

Comment: BTW - `.cleaned_data` gets totally cleared if there are any errors; it will only get populated if `.is_valid()` succeeds.

Comment: Shazam, that's it. I'll post the answer in full. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and found no ready solution. So we did ours (https://github.com/vialink/vlk-django-jsonfield).